# How to configure Antialiasing Fonts in Markdown Preview in PhpStorm Linux?

Tags: linux, phpstorm

I use Arch Linux and PhpStorm 2017.1

The font rendering for code itself is quite good but in Markdown Preview is terrible see screenshot section on the right eg. bulleted list text "The Solr admin...").
Where can I configure the font used for Markdown Preview?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally I found the solution.

In Settings>Languages & Frameworks>Markdown>Preview select Preview Browser: JavaFX WebView and check Use grayscale rendering for JavaFX preview.